# how can i separate socket.io to socket.js file, and use it within router.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

i have express/node.js app, and i would like to separate socket.io logic, from app.js to it's own file, and then to use in routes.js.

this is the way that i want to go:

app.js

```
const app = require('express')();
const http = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
```

sockets.js

```
function updatePageRoute(routerLocationParam) {
    console.log('in socket');
    //console.log(io);
    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
        io.emit('routerLocation', 'someone visited {' + routerLocationParam + '} page');
    })
}

module.exports = {updatePageRoute: updatePageRoute};
```

and routes.js

```
router.get('/a', function (req, res) {
    console.log('in a');
    const a = 'a';
    socketFun.updatePageRoute(a);
    res.send({name: 'a'});
});
```

I tried various ways to make this work, but i simlpy can't find the solution, i can't export **io** properly from app.js to socket.js